# How to http stream FFMPEG encoded frames with VLC

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc

I have a python script that write images (numpy arrays) on the standard output.
I want to keep this frames and encode them h264 with FFMPEG, using GPU, then give it to vlc to expose a stream over http.

Here there's a working example of my apporach, without the part of h264 encoding:

```
python3 script.py | ffmpeg -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -f rawvideo -i - -vcodec copy -f avi - | cvlc --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=25
--rawvid-width=1920 --rawvid-height=1080 --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --no-audio --sout '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{user=pippo,pwd=pluto,mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:10001/}'
```

Now, I'm having troubles in writing working pipes to do what I need.
Here the pipe I'm actually working on, FFMPEG process is managed by GPU, but VLC cannot correctly manage the flow, I suppose, in fact I can connect to VLC from another VLC instance used as client, but then I got an error in which VLC client cannot open MRL.

Here the pipe:

```
python3 script.py | ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -i - -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -f h264 - | cvlc --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=25 --rawvid-width=1920 --rawvid-height=1080 --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --no-audio --sout '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{user=pippo,pwd=pluto,mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:10001/}'
```

I don't understand how to set vlc parameters in order to manage the incoming stream. I also could have made errors in ffmpeg pipe, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: please share logs/error messages

Comment: I have no errors server side, but client side when I try to connect I got this message
`Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://x.x.x.x:10001/'. Check the log for details.`
However it fails after the insert of username and password

Comment: With this pipe `python3 script.py | ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s:v 1920x1080 -r 24 -i - -c:v h264_nvenc -f h264 - | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mjpg,vb=2500,fps=24,acodec=none}:standard{access=http{user=pippo,pwd=pluto,mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:8554/}" :demux=h264` I can also read frames from client. The last step is to remove vlc transcode, that give me the same problem when connecting